Pgfplots calculates plot wrongly
I am getting crazy about the following problem: A straight line y=0 should be plotted, but a function with a negative slope is plotted:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\def\epsE{1.0}
\def\kappa{0.3}
\def\c{0.3}
\def\aaa{(\kappa/2.0)-(\epsE*\c/2.0)} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [declare function={
lin(\x)=\aaa*\x;}]
      
\begin{axis}[
  samples=100,
  ]
  \addplot [very thick,orange,domain=-10:10] {lin(x)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

One can verify that \aaa is equal to zero, hence the plot of lin(x) should be a horizontal line at y=0. Instead, I get the plot below as output. What am I missing here???


Do not use \def\c{0.3}, this breaks the "¸" accents in pdfTeX. As a rule of thumb you should never use \def on a one-letter control word. Also \def\kappa removes the control sequence to typeset a lower case Greek kappa. You should use \newcommand* instead of \def to make sure not to accidentally break things.

Apart from the (important) problems noticed by Skillmon in the comment, that should be addressed, the problem here is that
lin(\x)=\aaa*\x

will become (by expansion)
lin(\x)=(\kappa/2.0)-(\epsE*\c/2.0)*\x

Can you see the problem here? The expression there will compute to 0.15-0.15*\x...
So basically, you missed a couple of parentheses, which were needed because the \def mechanism is textual expansion. That is also the reason why using the function definition (which has algebraic semantics) works.
So I suggest using the declare function for everything, avoiding the redefinition clashes you have in your code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [declare function={
        epsE=1.0;
        kappa=0.3;
        c=0.3;
        aaa=(kappa/2.0)-(epsE*c/2.0);
        lin(\x)=aaa*\x;
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        samples=100,
        ]
        \addplot [very thick,orange,domain=-10:10] {lin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I can answer myself: aaa should be decleared as a function, rather than a definition. The following works as expected:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\def\epsE{1.0}
\def\kappa{0.3}
\def\c{0.3}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [declare function={
aaa=(\kappa/2.0)-(\epsE*\c/2.0); 
lin(\x)=aaa*\x;
    }
]
      
\begin{axis}[
  samples=100,
  ]
  \addplot [very thick,orange,domain=-10:10] {lin(x)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here is the correct plot: 

Try a constant. Why do you think \aaa is zero ?

\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\def\epsE{1.0}
\def\kappa{0.3}
\def\c{0.3}
\def\aaa{(\kappa/2.0)-(\epsE*\c/2.0)} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [declare function={
lin(\x)=\aaa*\x;}]
      
\begin{axis}[
  samples=100,
  ]
  \addplot [very thick,orange,domain=-10:10] {lin(x)};
  \addplot [red,domain=-10:10] {0};
  \addplot [blue,domain=-10:10] {1.5};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

